# How to send data between two server using CURL in Codeigniter?

Tags: php, codeigniter, curl

I have two Servers:

**1. Licensing**

**2. Provisioning**

Now a client(android/ios device) sends a request to license server. So there we get some parameters from **GET** which I forward to Provisioning server, using **CURL** like this:

```
  $skey = $this->input->get('site_id');
  $uid  = $this->input->get('user_id'); 
  $url =  "http://127.0.0.1/example.com?site_key=".$skey."&uid=".$uid;

  $wget_cmd = "wget --no-check-certificate \"".$url."\" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ";
  //echo($wget_cmd);
  //exec($wget_cmd);
  // create a new cURL resource
  $ch = curl_init();
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
  // set URL and other appropriate options
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
  //curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
  // grab URL and pass it to the browser
  curl_exec($ch);


  echo curl_error($ch);


  // close cURL resource, and free up system resources
  curl_close($ch);
```

Now the provisioning server has a file called **provisioning.php**. There I perform some DB operations based on the request from **License server** and generate a URL which I want to send back to the license server.

On provisioning I generate a URL like this based on DB operations:

```
$uri = site_url('/uploads/'.$user_ini['custom_ini_filename'].'.ini');

$ini_url =  json_encode($uri,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);
```

Here I want to return this **`$ini_url`** back to license server.

> 1. How do I do this?
> 2. How to access this `$ini_url` on the license server ?

Comment: If you want just return URL instead output data to browser, you have to use `CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER` option set to 1. [Docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.curl-setopt.php).

Comment: @Tpojka how to access the $ini_url on license server? I want to use the value of that for further operations

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Set CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER to 1 and simply assign the response from curl_exec($ch) to a variable:

**License Server**

```
  $skey = $this->input->get('site_id');
  $uid  = $this->input->get('user_id'); 
  $url =  "http://127.0.0.1/example.com?site_key=".$skey."&uid=".$uid;

  $wget_cmd = "wget --no-check-certificate \"".$url."\" >/dev/null 2>/dev/null ";

  $ch = curl_init();
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, FALSE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_VERBOSE, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HTTPGET, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_TIMEOUT, 300);
  curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);

  // The blow variable stores the response from provision server
  $response_from_provision_server = curl_exec($ch);

  echo curl_error($ch);

  curl_close($ch);
```

You will also need to echo the contents of $ini_url from the provision server, this being the output that is sent back to License Server in response to the curl_exec() call.

**Provisioning Server**

```
$uri = site_url('/uploads/'.$user_ini['custom_ini_filename'].'.ini');

$ini_url =  json_encode($uri,JSON_UNESCAPED_SLASHES);

// echo the $ini_url variable
echo $ini_url;
```

Comment: Thank you so much @Null Reference

Comment: i want to pass this:`$skey = $this->input->get('site_id');`
  `$uid  = $this->input->get('user_id');`  to provisioning server from the current license server as two variables how may i do that?

Comment: Use json_encode and json_decode like such: License `echo json_encode(array('skey' => $this->input->get('site_id'), 'uid' => $this->input->get('user_id')))` Provision `$response = json_decode(curl_exec($ch))` Response becomes php std object. Access like such `$response->skey` `$response->uid`. Haven't tested this but it looks like it's right.